# Filename PHP conventions

Tags: php, filenames, conventions

I've developed many web applications over the past time and I never found myself adhering to any naming conventions when it comes to filenames. I have a PHP view where you can add users. Here are some suggestions I used over the time occasionally now and then this and that. So, is there anything like a convention to it or is it arbitrary?

- user_add.blade.php
- users_add.blade.php
- user_add.blade.php
- add_user.blade.php
- add_users.blade.php
- useradd.blade.php
- adduser.blade.php

Comment: Why not visit official php site? Also what you are asking is from laravel right? I think laracast might help you

Comment: you do, whatever you like, john :)

Answer (score 1):

The file naming system are arbitary. There is no particular method of naming a file. Use what you like. There is only restrictions in naming a Class or writing a variable. There are no standard naming conventions

Comment: All right, thank you. Is there still something which is considered good or bad practise?

Comment: There's nothing about naming a file. Use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php.
>   The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

Comment: He's taking about view. Not a class name

Comment: So why he cant use the same logic and for view files? (-;